# elasticsearch - minimum_should_match + phrase query

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to use a minimum_should_match on a phrase query?  Eg "quick brown dog"  could match `"I have a quick dog"` and score higher than `"dogs run around but the cat is quick"` assuming a high enough slop and a minimum match of "2".

I can't find any examples of this.  If a phrase match cannot do it, is there another way to accomplish this?

Comment: just tried it and it seems it's not supported.  So really the question is how to accomplish this in another way.

Answer (score 1):

I saw there were upvotes for this question so I'll post how I approached it.  I took the phrase "quick brown dog" (#1) and split it into three new phrases "quick brown"(#2) "quick dog" (#3) and "brown dog" (#4) and applied a these three along with the original as parts of a bool query (each was a "should" clause").

The first example document I gave `I have a quick dog` would match only #3 and the second document would not match any of them.  Therefore the first document would match, which is what I was after.

In this example there I wanted a minimum word match of 2 - if you needed more you would create larger shingles.

FYI - I think this might also be possible using a shingle token filter (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-shingle-tokenfilter.html) on the search.  See [Elastic search- search_analyzer vs index_analyzer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15923480/elastic-search-search-analyzer-vs-index-analyzer) for more info.  I didn't try this and I'm not sure if it works with the phrase queries and slop - but it would be great if it does.